# Unable to plot in R some locations over a shapefile

Tags: coordinate-system, r, rgdal, plot

I have a shapefile of polygons that I got from [here](https://docs.digital.mass.gov/dataset/massgis-data-zip-codes-5-digit-here-navteq), and a CSV file with longitude, latitude data (i.e. lon= -71.4; lat=42.5).

The shapefile has the following CRS information: `"+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.71666666666667 +lat_2=42.68333333333333 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000 +y_0=750000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"`

I can plot the shapefile and the location CSV file separately, but I have not been able to do it jointly.

Any idea what is going wrong in the code below?

```
shp <- readOGR('zipcodes_nt', 
               'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
coords = c(-71.42043,42.50242)
sp <- SpatialPoints(coords)
proj4string(sp) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326") # Google use WGS84.
sp84 <- spTransform(sp, CRS("+proj=lcc +lat_1=41.71666666666667 +lat_2=42.68333333333333 +lat_0=41 +lon_0=-71.5 +x_0=200000 +
                                                 y_0=750000 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
plot(shp)
plot(sp84, col="red", add=TRUE) # do not add anything!
```

Comment: This code fails with an error at `sp <- SpatialPoints(coords)` - do you get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your code. `SpatialPoints` cannot be constructed from an atomic vector of coordinates. The following works fine:

```r
library(sp)
library(rgdal)

download.file('http://download.massgis.digital.mass.gov/shapefiles/state/zipcodes_nt.zip',
              f <- tempfile(), mode='wb')
unzip(f, exdir=tempdir())
p <- readOGR(file.path(tempdir(), 'ZIPCODES_NT_POLY.shp'))

xy <- SpatialPoints(cbind(-71.42043,42.50242), CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
xy2 <- spTransform(xy, CRS(proj4string(p)))

plot(p)
points(xy2, col='red', pch=20)
```

[image]